# How do I insert NULL field in Access using find and replace

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access-2007

I wanted to find out if you can add a NULL value in to an empty field in Access using find and replace. I am moving my Access DB over to SQL but the empty fields in Access when copied over to SQL do not have NULL written in them and I am having to copy and paste NULL into all the empty fields in SQL.

Is there a way using find and replace, to make the empty fields a NULL field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this query after your import

```
    UPDATE myTable set MyColumn = NULL WHERE MyColumn = ''
```

Comment: Space-filled is a possibility as well as zero-length, is it not?

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen Moonen, it worked apart from your marks at the end. I found out on another search on line that it has to be '' on the end instead of "".